# how do I add private dependency to DESCRIPTION file for R dev package?

Tags: r, bitbucket, r-package, remotes

I have built a new package (let's call it `myNewPackage`) in R, which uses a private package (let's call it `privatePackage`) stored in my company's bitbucket repo.

Based on some replies I have found on Google (including [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/vignettes/dependencies.html)), I have understood that I need to add `Remotes:` to my package DESCRIPTION file.

Here's what I tried:

```
Remotes: bitbucket::my_company_username/privatePackage
Imports: 
    bigrquery,
    ...
    privatePackage
```

but when I try to install `myNewPackage` in Rstudio:

```
install_bitbucket(repo = "my_company_username/myNewPackage@dev_branch", auth_user = my_user, password = my_pwd)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to install 'myNewPackage' from Bitbucket:
cannot open URL 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/my_company_username/privatePackage/commit/HEAD'
```

I suspect the issue is caused by the fact that I have not defined my username and password when I type `Remotes:` in the DESCRIPTION file of `myNewPackage`, therefore R is trying to access `privatePackage` repo on Bitbucket but it doesn't have any authorization to do it. Unfortunately I don't know where I should add them to the code.

NOTE: `my_user` and `my_pwd` defined in `install_bitbucket()` above are sufficient to access `privatePackage` repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by editing the environment variables, following `install_bitbucket()` reference guide [here](https://remotes.r-lib.org/reference/install_bitbucket.html):

```
Sys.setenv("BITBUCKET_USER" = my_usr)
Sys.setenv("BITBUCKET_PASSWORD" = my_pwd)
```